# How to delete android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in my application

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have written an application which I want to publish in a market. The problem is that market asks me to delete `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` 
and `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

I removed these two extra permissions from Manifest but when I check my application permissions in my phone, I can see the "modify or delete the contents of your SD card" in the permissions list.
This app is using SQLite database and I'm not sure the problem is because of that or not.

I've searched this permission in my app completely but I've not found any related code!

The only point is that this app is using below dependency:
`com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1`

Please guide me

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.ehin.darookhane">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:name="com.ehin.darookhane.ApplicationClass"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_darookhane"
        android:label="داروخانه همراه"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:label,android:supportsRtl"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">

        <activity
            android:name="com.ehin.darookhane.NetworkActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MTN.SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ehin.darookhane.ActivityList"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ehin.darookhane.ActivityContent"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ehin.darookhane.ActivityFavorite"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />



        <activity
            android:name="com.ehin.darookhane.MTN.LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ehin.darookhane.MTN.IntroActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.ehin.darookhane.MainActivity"></activity>

        <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: Try to uninstall the app -> Clean or Rebuild your project -> and install it again

Comment: I've tried but it's not working

Comment: can you post your activity code?

Comment: thanks for your guidance. There are many activities, which activity should i load?

Comment: I've attached my MainActivity

Comment: Have you include any library which contain image pick code ?

Comment: Your app probably uses a library that has a lib-manifest that wants extra permissions. The dependencies are in your build.gradle file(s)

Comment: Thanks a lot "k3b". This is the best response. It is written we should add these codes in Manifest :
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="remove"/>     and      
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="remove"/>